# Generics and nullish types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I'm interested in a generic function that will give a compile time error if called with arguments of different types.

Initially, I've tried something like that:

```
type genericFunc = {
    <T>(a:T, b:T): boolean
}

let isEq: genericFunc = (a,b) => { return a === b }
```

When I try to call it like so:

```
isEq(1,"str")
```

I get a compile time error, as expected. However, when I try to:

```
isEq(1, null)
```

or:

```
isEq(1, undefined)
```

It all compiles without complaining. Per vscode, the type of `isEq(1, null)` is inferred to as:

```
let isEq: <number | null>(a: number | null, b: number | null) => boolean
```

Setting `"strictNullChecks": true` in my tsconfig.json does not change that.

To summarize, I'm interested in the following questions:

1. Why are the types inferred this way?
2. Should I define the type `genericFunc` differently?
3. Is there a way to enforce a stricter type inference when generics and nullish types are involved?

Many Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the great answer, you could also use a conditional type: `<T extends null | undefined ? : never : T>(a: T, b: T) => ...`

Answer (score 1):

`T` can be a union, so it could always just be a union of the two argument to satisfy the function's type.

Though I'm not really sure why `isEq(1, "str")` fails since it seems like `number | string` seems like it should be the inferred type there, but helping out the compiler with a `isEq<number | string>(1, "str")` does seem to allow it there. I wish I could tell you why that happens.

---

An improvement would be to have two generic parameters, one for each argument, and ensure that one extends the other.

```
<T, U extends T>(a:T, b:U): boolean
```

Now `U` must be the same type (or a subtype) of `T` in order to be allowed.

```
// works
isEq('asd', 'qwe')

// All type errors:
isEq(1, "str")
isEq(1, null)
isEq(1, undefined)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=19&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA5hB2EBOBLAxgMQK7zVAvFAN4CwAUFJVADwAqANFAKpQQAewCAJgM5S0A+ABQBDAFwMoAIzFMAlGOkB7JQBsII+OQC+5cuuBQUPAKIBHRXESpMOPIVH0pcggOJQkEYFiTwoIgnxCKShdMnIAegioAHclJABrHnJjcyEAchEeLnTGdLMYiHS5FNMzISJxKAAmAGYAFm1GSsUARjrGGSh6gFYANm0S8LIo1iQkeOSyVPLWxgAiHmAkeaGZoTmoeCxVVTWyjcYcLggAMxRELiG9MiA)

---

All that said, the "same" type is a trickier thing than you might expect.

This solution would allow:

```
isEq({a: 234}, {a: 123, b: 456})
```

Because the second argument is a subtype of the first. Meaning it would be assignable to that type. Which raises the question:

Are these the same type?

```
const a = { a: 123 }
const b = { a: 456, b: 789 }
```

How about these?

```
type Test = { a: number, b?: number }
const a: Test = { a: 123 }
const b: Test = { a: 456, b: 789 }
```

Or these?

```
class A { public num: number }
class B extends A { public str: string }
```

Or?

```
const a: string | number = 123
const b: string | number = 'asd'
```

Because all these would be considered equal by this approach, because `b` in each case is assignable to the the type of `a`. Maybe that's fine, maybe it's not.

How to compare these types really depends on how you intend to use this.

Comment: "I wish I could tell you why that happens" See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31617 ; it's an intentional/heuristic tradeoff to catch errors.  For multiple types in covariant type positions the compiler could always infer a union to make it work (or even `unknown`) but that's not always helpful.  The exact rules are ‍♂️.  Also see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312 for related discussion.

Comment: Thanks Alex. The solution you offer seems to work in most cases. But (a) It is not clear why; Since 'number' extends 'undefined | number', I'd expect the compiler to infer a union here too. (b) It is non-intuitive, since I'd expect the signature '(a:T, b:T) => boolean' to enforce that 'T is a subtype of T' without you explicitly tell the compiler to enforce it (c) It is not symmetric - If T is a subtype of U, you'd get a compile time error.

Comment: In the case of `<T>(a:T, b:T) => void` the compiler takes a best guess about how to to infer one type from two values, and how it does this is can be a little strange, as @jcalz notes in his comment. In the case of `<T, U extends T>(a:T, b:U) => void` there is only one value to infer the type of `T` and only one for `U`. This gives you a lot more control since it removes all ambiguity about how things should be inferred. It infers `T` from `a`, and infers `U` from `b`, and _then_ it enforces the constraint `U extends T`.